# Select div with class in Jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, filtering, slick.js

I'm having troubles with this : I have a list of div displayed as a slider. I select some of those divs with their class to show only specific dates. Now, I need to output also in list and be able to do the same. I'm using the slick slider. To output the list, I kill the slider. Then, when I click on my date, instead of showing only the div with the specific class, it hides them. 
Here is my code : 
'

```
    <ul class="month">
        <li data-filter="201511" class="js-filter">november 2015</li>
        <li data-filter="201512" class="js-filter">decembre 2015</li>
        <li data-filter="201601" class="js-filter">January 2016</li>
        <li data-filter="201602" class="js-filter">February 2016</li>
        <li data-filter="201603" class="js-filter">March 2016</li>
        <li class="js-filter reset">All months</li>
    </ul>
<div class="carousel slick-initialized slick-slider" id="touslesvolsenslider">          
    <div class="slick-list draggable">
        <div class="slick-track">
            <div class="vol 201511 London slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-4"></div>
            <div class="vol 201512 London slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-4"></div>                
            <div class="vol 201602 London slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-4"></div>
            <div class="vol 201603 London slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-4"></div>
            <div class="vol 201511 Paris slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-4"></div>
            <div class="vol 201512 Paris slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-4"></div>
            <div class="vol 201603 Paris slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-4"></div>
            <div class="vol 201602 Paris slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $('.carousel').slick({
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 4,
            infinite: true,
        });

        var filtered = false;

        $('.js-filter').on('click', function(){
            var customType = $( this ).data('filter');
            if (filtered === false) {
                $('.carousel').slick('slickFilter','.'+ customType);
                filtered = true;
            } else {
                $('.carousel').slick('slickFilter','.'+ customType);
                filtered = true;
            }
        });

        $('.reset').on('click', function(){
            $('.carousel').slick('slickUnfilter');
            $(this).text('Tous les mois');
            filtered = false;
        });

        $('.inlist').on('click', function(){
            var filtered = false;
            $('.carousel').slick('slickUnfilter');
            $('.carousel').slick('unslick');
            $('.js-filter').addClass('triervols');
            $('.js-filter').removeClass('js-filter');
        });

        $('.inslider').on('click', function(){
            $('.triervols').addClass('js-filter');
            $('.carousel').slick({
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 4,
                infinite: true,
            });
        });
    </script>'
```